# Cygwin: why we required "export SHELLOPTS; set -o igncr"

Tags: cygwin

When I tried running my shell script earlier it said end of file error.
But after running the following two commands it started running fine.

```
export SHELLOPTS 
set -o igncr
```

please explain what is the reason behind this.

Comment: Which 2 commands? please post the relevant data in question!

Comment: export SHELLOPTS
and set -o igncr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set -o igncr` causes the shell ignore windows line endings (skip `\r`). Another solution would be to fix the script by running `dos2unix` on it.

Comment: `dos2unix` on script won't help, subscripts will still be broken.